# Conditional Delegate Question

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's say I open a form and want to attach a command to it after it closes.

```
FormZombie FormZombie = new FormZombie();
FormZombie.Show();
FormZombie.FormClose += delegate{Utilities.DoSomethingCool()};
```

How can I make Utilities.DoSomethingCool() trigger only executes depending on what happens in FormZombie?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add the conditional check into your delegate:

```
FormZombie formZombie = new FormZombie(); 
formZombie.Show(); 
formZombie.FormClose += 
    delegate
    {
        if (formZombie.AteEnoughBrains)
            Utilities.DoSomethingCool();
    };
```

Comment: Reed, how can I implement this if I'm two forms deep? 
Form1 opens Form2, Form2 opens Form3, Form3.Closed += delegate{method from Form1}

Comment: You should to pass a reference into the forms - ie: Give Form1 a reference to your form1 instance (this), then Form2 can pass the form1 instance into form3, etc.  That way, it can handle this directly.